# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined while upgrading to webpack 5

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

This runtime error is thrown because partner team's code inside node_modules uses process. like below:

> const isTestEnv = process?.env?.SOME_FIELD !== undefined;

1. My first question is why does webpack throw this error at all since the optional chaining is being used here?

When I try to fix the error by defining plugin, the error still remains the same

Snipping from my webpack plugin:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process?.env?.JEST_WORKER_ID': undefined,
    }),
]
```

2. I cannot use a polyfill for this since the code changes will be required at partner team end because they are not assigning `process` from any import. they just use it like a global variable. what option do I have ?

Comment: Can you share the complete Webpack configuration?

Comment: complete webpack configuration is large and split into multiple files. why do you need the complete config ?

Comment: Are you trying to access this `process` environment variable inside the browser code or the Webpack build script?

Comment: inside the browser code